# did maven killed the ant or it is still alive?

Tags: maven, gradle, ant

we all know that there is community supporting `maven` and since maven has some advanced features so most people recommend as building tool and gradle is in picture too but is using `ant` today will be considered as old fashioned or it still gives same competition that it used to be?

did maven has achieved more then ant or ant is still alive?

Comment: Using ant is in my opinion archaic. You have to do the dependency management via hand. this is a huge blocker for agile development practices. Also all build scripts look very different. Maven adds conventions to solve that issue.

Comment: Ant serves a different purpose, but using ist for project compilation like for Java projects ist a dead-end. I do not contribute to non-Maven projects. Too much fuzz.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ant is the grandaddy of the all, starting out as a Java version of "make" (an even older build tool). Along came Maven 1.0 (which we all pretend never existed) to be replaced by Maven 2.0. For a brief time the Java world was split between those who understood the importance of dependency management and those who didn't. Eventually all tools now copy what Maven pioneered and we now have Gradle, a modern build tool built on the shoulders of giants :-)

So cool kids Gradle. Most Java developers are using Maven (frequently bundled and hidden away by their Eclipse IDE) and old school release engineers still have productive careers maintaining corporate applications that use Ant.

Comment: In your short history you missed Maven 3+ ;-)

Comment: then I think starting with maven is only suitable  approach ;) and thanks for your time :)

Comment: Also, many maven builds will call out to ant (via maven-antrun-plugin) to perform tasks. And gradle has [deep ant integration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/ant.html) and many gradle plugins are simply wrappers around ant invocations. So by providing an ant task, a project can be usable in ant, maven and gradle. Win!